# Удалить самые длинные слова из файла

Tags: c++

Дан текст (2–3 строки) в файле F1. Текст состоит
из слов, отделенных друг от друга пробелами. Описать
функцию, которая находит самое длинное слово в строке
и удаляет его. Преобразовать все строки текста и записать
новый текст в файл F2. Буду благодарен, если не набегут умники со словами: "хаха в гугле забанили?)". Я уже поискал все что можно, если бы нашел решение, то не писал бы сюда.

```
ifstream fout("F1.txt");
char line[100];
fout.getline(line, 100);
char* words = strtok(line, " ");
char* maxword = words;
char* curword;
for (size_t i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    curword = words;
    if (maxword < curword) {
        maxword = curword;
    }

}
cout << maxword;
```

Comment: Ну сюда несомненно набегут умники, жаждущие спросить - а покажите, что вы, собственно, сделали? Строку-то из файла прочитали?

Comment: @MBo, строку я прочитал, но лучше полноценно работающий код, ибо если я покажу свой код, дискуссия повернется в сторону засирания моего кода, а мне этого не очень хочется

Comment: @intskull, вы не можете знать, что будет. Вы боитесь, что какие-то дядьки и тетьки будут осуждать ваш код? Забейте и просто выложите его, вам подскажут что правильно, что не правильно.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, я не бо.сь что мой код будут обсуждать, я боюсь что в моем коде все не правильно, ибо в плюсах я дарницкий хлеб и легче новый скрипт написать, чем мусолить мой. Выложил код, там наметки небольшие

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации данной задачи можно использовать *token*. Делить предложения на слова **->** находить размер слова функцией *[str].length()* **->** первое слово брать за минимум размер слова **->** самое большое удалять присваивая *[str] = '\0'* **->** с запись в другой файл сделать через буфер копирования и записи.

```
            string str;
            getline(file, str, '\0');
            char* token = strtok((char*)str.c_str(), ";,\n");
            while (token != nullptr) {
                
                    
                token = strtok(NULL, ",;\n");
            }
```

Comment: А можно это все человеческим языком как-нибудь?) О токенах в первый раз слышу, что это такое без понятия. А сама логика мне ясна, так то я уже все в голове решил, у меня проблемы с реализацией

Comment: Правил. Вставил пример использования с токеном. В цикл вставляйте действия связанные со словом. Слово храниться в токене до тех пор - пока вы не очистите его

Comment: Не получается, я закинул код в вопрос, подскажите что дальше делать, пожалуйста. Лучше, конечно, в формате кода.

Comment: Давайте лучше перейдем в телеграмм. @nikakoye